# Is Flutter have support playing AES128 Encrypted HLS playlist for iPhone

Tags: ios, flutter, aes, http-live-streaming

I am working for an OTT player application for iOS using Flutter sdk. Is  flutter support playback of  HLS AES128 encrypted streams by using direct sdk or using any official or thirdparty plugin

Comment: did you find any solution for this requirement? Thanks